# How can I place a UITableView on a UIViewController programmatically so that it doesn't take up the whole view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to have a ViewController that has a table view on the top half of the screen, and a button under it.  I'm assuming there's a simple way to do this.  Every way I have tried so far ends up in the bottom half of the view being inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that you cannot use a subclass of `UITableViewController`. You need to enable the `datasource` and `delegate` protocols explicitly in a `UIViewController`.

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate>
// variables and properties
@end
```

Don't forget to assign `self` as `delegate` and `datasource` of your tableview.

Now you can just put the table view anywhere by giving it an appropriate `frame` and you can also put a button at the bottom.

Hint: the standard way to "put a button at the bottom" is to use a `UIToolBar`. With that you could use the normal table view controller without having to worry about the protocols. But your approach is also feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have put a sample image to get the clear idea. but AFAI understood, i try to give the answer accordingly :

You can set the frame especially height of TableView just half the size of the height of your UIViewController.

Then rest of the space of UIViewCobtroller you can create another view where you can place your button as you have already done so far.

> You can add the button in your UITableView's footer section.

Comment: Button in footer would not work, as it might scroll off screen.

Comment: Then he has no option AFAIK, or else he can put the button on NavigationBar. Its all depends on his UI design..